# Why Searching Gmail Doesn't Return Results If Searched Not From Beginning?

Tags: gmail, search, keyword

For example, when searching with **"quest"** for content containing word *"questions"* starting from beginning of word, Gmail returns result:

[image]

However if searching with **"est"**, no results are being returned.

Comment: This is **not** a **search** function, this is an **autocomplete** one. That's why you have to start at the begining of your contact Name or address.

Comment: Do you know how to search instead of autocomplete when composing email message so I can find certain contact fast?

Comment: No, I can't see any eay way. You can go to [Google Contacts](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#contacts), search for the contact and compose mail to the contact

Comment: @JMax, see w3d’s answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Autocomplete

Typing in the "To" field autocompletes the contact from the start of a word, not just the start of the contact name or email address. So, if you have a contact called "Joe Bloggs", you can start *searching* on the `b` of "Bloggs" ie:

[image: Gmail To Field Autocomplete]

## Contact Search

If, however, you want to do a complete search of your contacts, you can click on the label "To" and this opens all your contacts in a handy popup, complete with a **search box**. Select all the contacts that you wish to address the email to and click **Select**.

[image]

Comment: Or **Cc** or **Bcc** —for both situations.